# Python3 multiprocessing shared dictionary consume by all process

Tags: python-3.x, printing, multiprocessing, sys

I'm beginner for multiprocessing, 
i would like to use multiprocessing for parallel code running with streaming data.
To start good, I have coded below and got error. 
Could you please tell me correct way to print on the screen.

Code:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

def producer(dic, name):
    for i in range(10000):
        dic["A"] = i
        time.sleep(2)


def consumer(dic, name):
    for i in range(10000):
        aval = dic.get("A")
        #print(f" {name} - Val = {aval}")
        sys.stdout.write(f" {name} - Val = {aval}")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(2.2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dic = manager.dict()
    Process(target=producer, args=(dic,"TT")).start()
    time.sleep(1)
    Process(target=consumer, args=(dic,"Con1")).start()
    Process(target=consumer, args=(dic,"Con2")).start()
```

When I run the same in the windows console, I got below error, how can I print Consumer's print function in the console.Thanks

```
(base) PS D:\> python .\mulpro.py
Process Process-3:
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 811, in
_callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _
bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in ru
n
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\mulpro.py", line 19, in consumer
    aval = dic.get("A")
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 815, in
_callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 802, in
_connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 490, i
n Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 691, i
n PipeClient
    _winapi.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 811, in
_callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _
bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in ru
n
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\mulpro.py", line 19, in consumer
    aval = dic.get("A")
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 815, in
_callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 802, in
_connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 490, i
n Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 691, i
n PipeClient
    _winapi.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _
bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in ru
n
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\mulpro.py", line 13, in producer
    dic["A"] = i
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 818, in
_callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, i
n send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, i
n _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the main process doesn't wait for two children process, so make your code like this could work:

```
def run():
    manager = Manager()
    dic = manager.dict()
    Process(target=producer, args=(dic,"TT")).start()
    time.sleep(1)
    Process(target=consumer, args=(dic,"Con1")).start()
    Process(target=consumer, args=(dic,"Con2")).start()
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

However it's very strange that if I append a dead loop in main instead of using another function, it still raise that exception. Anyway, the code above could help.